# Capturing multi-line data using Chosen jQuery plugin for search button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex, jquery-chosen

I built an app that allows users to choose from a list of over 7,000 ingredients they already have and search for recipes that include them (using a recipe aggregator API). At first I had two search forms, a huge long multiple search scrolling list to let them choose the ingredients, which on submit populates another list, whose submit button sends the data via AJAX and outputs the recipes. I included the Chosen jQuery plugin for the first search and want to get rid of the second form entirely to make the first search output the recipes. So I'm trying to capture the data in the chosen text area, which I can then send to my javascript ajax function.

I figured out that the ingredients a user chooses using chosen is captured by this:

```
    $('.chosen-choices').text();
    "
    kale chips
    sugar
    "
```

I think I could use regular expressions to get that data, but am new to them and need help with what exactly to use in order to capture multi-line multi-word data. Here's what I have so far (using ):

```
^\A\w(...)\s(...)
```

But this only captures "kale chi"

Please advise with what you think would be the best way forward.

Comment: Can't you just split the `text` by `\n`?

Comment: @royhowie what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Do you want an array of all the options (1 option per line)?

Comment: Thanks all. I ended up using .each method in my js file and some regex, so it looks like this now: `var content = $('.search-choice');
content.each(function(){
  
  var query = (encodeURI($(this).text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')));
  console.log(query);`